# mac directory structure to text converter

Tags: text, architecture, directory, structure, converters

Im looking for a tool that would convert a given directory into a text based directory in form of:

im working with macOS, maybe there is a browser based tool for this?

```
./directory
|
+-- subdirectory1/
|   |
|   + fileA.md  
|
+-- subdirectory2/
    |
    + fileA.md  
    + ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a Unix tool that will do this called [`tree`](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/). This tool will output the directory tree structure of a given folder. It is a command line tool which means that you will have to use the terminal to get your results. Typing `tree -d ~` will, for example, output the tree structure of you home directory.

Although it is not included by default on MacOS you can install it yourself. You can download and compile the source on their homepage ([link](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/)) or use a package manager like HomeBrew to install it (`brew install tree`).